# Wireless pci Card not working (RT3062)

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, wireless-access-point, lspci

i ask in many question portals in the internet. My wireless card Ralink RT3062 dont work on my Kubuntu 14.04 system.

I do many commands in the shell:

```
 root@jonas-PC:/home/jonas# uname -a
Linux jonas-PC 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:23:34 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
root@jonas-PC:/home/jonas# lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2   
00:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet [1039:0900] (rev 91)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] MS-6701 motherboard [1462:0900]
        Kernel driver in use: sis900
00:08.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R [1814:3062]
        Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R [1814:3062]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation NV17 [GeForce4 MX 420] [10de:0172] (rev a3)
root@jonas-PC:/home/jonas# 


jonas@jonas-PC:~$ iwconfig
 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off


    jonas@jonas-PC:~$ dmesg | grep rt2
[ 3327.217186] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3572, rev 0221 detected
[ 3327.227352] rt2x00mmio_regbusy_read() Indirect register access failed: offset=0x00000580, value=0xffffffff
[ 3327.529731] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0001 detected
[ 3327.570773] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2860.bin'
[ 3327.614600] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.34
[ 3328.412022] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3329.272021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3330.072121] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3330.876021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3331.676021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3332.476019] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3333.276018] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3334.076022] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3334.876021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3335.676019] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3336.476021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3337.276041] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3338.076022] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3338.876020] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3339.676020] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3340.476021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3341.276021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3342.076020] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3342.876021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3343.676019] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3344.476021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3345.276021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3346.076021] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3346.876019] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3347.676054] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
[ 3348.476020] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_load_firmware: Error - PBF system register not ready
```

lsmod:

```
jonas@jonas-PC:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
arc4                   16384  2 
rt2800pci              16384  0 
rt2800mmio             16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              86016  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              49152  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              618496  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
cfg80211              450560  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
snd_wavefront          36864  0 
snd_cs4236             32768  0 
snd_opl3_lib           20480  2 snd_wavefront,snd_cs4236
snd_intel8x0           40960  2 
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_wavefront,snd_opl3_lib
snd_ac97_codec        106496  1 snd_intel8x0
snd_wss_lib            28672  2 snd_wavefront,snd_cs4236
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                94208  4 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0,snd_wss_lib,snd_cs4236
snd_mpu401             16384  0 
snd_mpu401_uart        16384  3 snd_wavefront,snd_cs4236,snd_mpu401
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
rfcomm                 61440  0 
bnep                   20480  2 
bluetooth             430080  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_rawmidi            28672  3 snd_wavefront,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_seq_midi
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0 
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd_seq_device         16384  4 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_opl3_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28672  4 snd_wss_lib,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_opl3_lib
snd                    69632  18 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_wss_lib,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_wavefront,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_seq_device,snd_cs4236,snd_opl3_lib,snd_mpu401                                                                                      
i2c_sis96x             16384  0                                                                                                                
ns558                  16384  0                                                                                                                
soundcore              16384  1 snd                                                                                                            
8250_fintek            16384  0 
gameport               16384  2 ns558
shpchp                 32768  0 
parport_pc             32768  1 
mac_hid                16384  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     16384  0 
parport                40960  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0 
usbhid                 49152  0 
hid                    98304  3 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
nouveau              1208320  2 
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  20480  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    86016  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        114688  1 nouveau
sis900                 28672  0 
firewire_ohci          36864  0 
mii                    16384  1 sis900
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
drm                   286720  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
pata_acpi              16384  0 
floppy                 61440  0 
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
sis_agp                16384  1
```

I dont know whats wrong with my card ... It would be nice helping me :)